# Import Django models from outside the project

Tags: django, import, model, project

I'm working on an app which uses two tables from different databases.I manage to make the connection and make the tables structures in models.py, but now one I change the models.py file, I copy one of the tables in another python script, and I put the file elsewhere for other people to use it.My question it is possible in Django to import a model from outside the project? or the package?

The App is called banner_manager and in views.py I want to import a model called user from another project called django_models
when I try to import like this:
from ....models_django import models.py(in models.py it's the class "user" defined) it says: ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: Its possible, its just a case of setting up the correct environmental variables. As you haven't given much idea of the project and external structure, its difficult to advise what to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this directory to [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) for example:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/var/python/your-libs
```

And then just import package as normal:

```
import models_django
```

Comment: But now when i try to import from the lib folders: from table_class_corespondance import Users it give me this error RuntimeError: Model class table_class_corespondance.Users doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: You need to add your app to INSTALLED_APPS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34406473/5996922